# Jupyter Notebook/Python/BeautifulSoup - ImportError: cannot import name 'RubyParenthesisString' from 'bs4.element'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, importerror

Trying to import BeautifulSoup via Jupyter Notebook (run from cmd):

```
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`
```

I get the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'RubyParenthesisString' from 'bs4.element'

Checked that the import works perfectly fine if run via cmd

#Checked python version

```
python --version
```

> Python 3.8.8

#Checked pip version

```
pip --version
```

> pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\Tlhogi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

#Ran Python in cmd and verified that Beautiful soup works

```
python
```

> Python 3.8.8 (tags/v3.8.8:024d805, Feb 19 2021, 13:18:16) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> bs4.__version__
```

> '4.12.2'

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('html','html.parser')
>>> print(soup)
```

> html

```
>>> print(type(soup))
```

> <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>

Why doesn't this work in Jupyter Notebook even though it works via cmd?
How do I fix the problem?

Comment: What is the name of your python file? Is there any file called bs4.py or something along the lines in your working directory?

Comment: If you haven't inadvertently 'shadowed' something like krish is trying to warn you about, try running in a new cell **inside your notebook** `%pip install beautifulsoup4` based on [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installing-beautiful-soup) and [the modern install magic for Jupyter](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) to insure the installation occurs in the environment backing the kernel for the current active notebook. Then restart the kernel and try the import `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: @Wayne
Thanks for your suggestion but I decided to update pip, reinstall BeautifulSoup4 and restart the kernel before I saw your response.
This resolved the problem (not sure why)

Comment: @krish
I tried that based on older ImportError logs before sending my request; searched my directory for files named bs4 and there was only one. Thanks